# Initiating AJAX request from multiple buttons on the same page in Django

Tags: javascript, ajax, django

Ok, so I'm trying to add voting to my website(django based) using Ajax. I have multiple entries in one page, But right now my code only let users vote on the first entry. Please help me with the code so that users can vote on all of them.

First is the html code, basically it's just a vote button for users to vote

```html
{% for answer in answers %}<!-- django template -->
<strong id="vote_count">{{ answer.votes }}</strong> people vote this answer

{% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <button id="vote" data-answerid="{{answer.id}}" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span>
        Vote
        </button>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}<!-- end django template -->
```

Second, below is the django view that process the request

```
@login_required
def vote_answer(request):
  answer_id = None
  if request.method == 'GET':
      answer_id = request.GET['answer_id']

  votes = 0 
  if answer_id:
      answer = Answer.objects.get(id=answer_id)
      if answer:
          votes = answer.votes + 1
          answer.votes = votes
          answer.save()

  return HttpResponse(votes)
```

below is the url mapping:

```
url(r'^like_category/$', views.like_category, name='like_category'),
```

Finally is the javascript

```js
$('#vote').click(function(){
    var answerid;
    answerid = $(this).attr("data-answerid");
    $.get('/vote_answer/', {answer_id: answerid}, function(data){
               $('#vote_count').html(data);
               $('#vote').hide();
    });
});
```

Again, my problem is that of all the entries I have in one page, with this code I can only vote the first one. How can modify it so I can vote all of them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `class` instead of `id` on `<button>`, so that multiple buttons can share the same jQuery event handler.

```
<button class="vote" data-answerid="...">
```

Then you can do the following in JavaScript:

```
$(document).on("click", ".vote", function(){
    var answerid;
    answerid = $(this).attr("data-answerid");
    $.get('/vote_answer/', {answer_id: answerid}, function(data){
               $('#vote_count').html(data);
               $('#vote').hide();
    });
});
```

This will bind the event handler to click any `<button class=vote>`.

Also you should do AJAX POST instead of GET by HTTP semantics, because voting is a state changing operation. Otherwise the browser or the web proxies may cache the result (though jQuery have its own cache buster).

Comment: Thank you, totally works. Another question: to use POST, should I just change $.get to $.post ?

Comment: Please do not forget to mark the answer as the correct one if it solves your problem. Welcome to StackOverflow :)